Pine Script 5. How to draw lines (High, Low) for individual quarters of the year?
`Indicator of quarterly lines "Quarter & lines".
Quarters of the year.
Horizontal lines of the quarters.

:
Lines of Conditional Quarters in a year:
Day. Month - Day. Month
1st pair of lines (High, Low): on Friday of the 2nd week. 03 - 5. 06
2nd pair of lines (High, Low): on Friday of the 2nd week. 06 - 4. 09
3rd pair of lines (High, Low): on Friday of the 2nd week. 09 - 4. 12
4th pair of lines (High, Low): on Friday of the 2nd week. 12 - 6. 03

:
Horizontal lines of the block:


(above the values ​​on the graph, 2 px:)
High - yellow color (default)
(below the values ​​on the graph, 2 px: )
Low - color.navy (default)`
This is what I got, but it’s not quite what I needed.
//@version=5
indicator("Quarter & lines", overlay=true) //, max_lines_count=450)

//---- I ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//
//   Setting the colors for the High and Low lines
//
color clr_High = input.color(color.yellow, "Color High")
color clr_Low = input.color(color.navy, "Color Low")



//---- II ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


// 
//   Function to get the date of the second Friday of the month
// 
second_friday(y, m) =>
    first_day_of_month = timestamp(y, m, 1)
    first_day_of_month_dow = dayofweek(first_day_of_month)
    second_friday_day = 1 + (5 - first_day_of_month_dow + 7) % 7 + 7
    timestamp(y, m, second_friday_day)

// 
//   Defining quarter time intervals
// 
sec_friday_1 = second_friday(year, 3)
Q_1_start = sec_friday_1
Q_1_end = timestamp(year, 6, 5, 23, 59)

sec_friday_2 = second_friday(year, 6)
Q_2_start = sec_friday_2
Q_2_end = timestamp(year, 9, 4, 23, 59)

sec_friday_3 = second_friday(year, 9)
Q_3_start = sec_friday_3
Q_3_end = timestamp(year, 12, 4, 23, 59)

sec_friday_4 = second_friday(year, 12)
Q_3_start = sec_friday_4
Q_4_end = timestamp(year + 1, 3, 6, 23, 59)

// 
//   Function for getting bar index by time
// 
F_Get_BarIndexAtTime(_time) =>
    var int barIndex = na
    if (_time <= time and (_time > time[1] or bar_index == 0))
        barIndex := bar_index
    barIndex

// 
//   Getting bar indexes for each quarter
// 
inBar_q1_start = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", F_Get_BarIndexAtTime(Q_1_start))
inBar_q1_end   = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", F_Get_BarIndexAtTime(Q_1_end))

inBar_q2_start = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", F_Get_BarIndexAtTime(Q_2_start))
inBar_q2_end   = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", F_Get_BarIndexAtTime(Q_2_end))

inBar_q3_start = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", F_Get_BarIndexAtTime(Q_3_start))
inBar_q3_end   = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", F_Get_BarIndexAtTime(Q_3_end))

inBar_q4_start = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", F_Get_BarIndexAtTime(Q_3_start))
inBar_q4_end   = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", F_Get_BarIndexAtTime(Q_4_end))

// 
//   Function for determining High and Low for a quarter
// 
F_Get_High_Low(  startMonth, startDay,   endMonth, endDay  ) =>
    var float highPrice = na
    var float lowPrice = na
    if (month == startMonth and dayofmonth == startDay)
        highPrice := high
        lowPrice := low
    if (month >= startMonth and month <= endMonth)
        if (month == endMonth and dayofmonth > endDay)
            na
        else
            highPrice := math.max(highPrice, high)
            lowPrice := math.min(lowPrice, low)
    [highPrice, lowPrice]

// 
//  Definition of quarterly periods -     [highPrice, lowPrice]
// 
[q1_High,  q1_Low] = F_Get_High_Low( 3, dayofmonth(Q_1_start),   6, dayofmonth(Q_1_end) )
[q2_High, q2_Low] = F_Get_High_Low( 6, dayofmonth(Q_2_start),   9, dayofmonth(Q_2_end) )
[q3_High, q3_Low] = F_Get_High_Low( 9, dayofmonth(Q_3_start),   12, dayofmonth(Q_3_end) )
[q4_High, q4_Low] = F_Get_High_Low( 12, dayofmonth(Q_3_start),   3, dayofmonth(Q_4_end) )

// 
//   Drawing lines and marks
// 
if not na(inBar_q1_start) and not na(inBar_q1_end) and not na(q1_High) and not na(q1_Low)
    line.new(inBar_q1_start, q1_High, inBar_q1_end, q1_High, width=2, color=clr_High)
    line.new(inBar_q1_start, q1_Low, inBar_q1_end, q1_Low, width=2, color=clr_Low)

if not na(inBar_q2_start) and not na(inBar_q2_end) and not na(q2_High) and not na(q2_Low)
    line.new(inBar_q2_start, q2_High, inBar_q2_end, q2_High, width=2, color=clr_High)
    line.new(inBar_q2_start, q2_Low, inBar_q2_end, q2_Low, width=2, color=clr_Low)

if not na(inBar_q3_start) and not na(inBar_q3_end) and not na(q3_High) and not na(q3_Low)
    line.new(inBar_q3_start, q3_High, inBar_q3_end, q3_High, width=2, color=clr_High)
    line.new(inBar_q3_start, q3_Low, inBar_q3_end, q3_Low, width=2, color=clr_Low)

if not na(inBar_q4_start) and not na(inBar_q4_end) and not na(q4_High) and not na(q4_Low)
    line.new(inBar_q4_start, q4_High, inBar_q4_end, q4_High, width=2, color=clr_High)
    line.new(inBar_q4_start, q4_Low, inBar_q4_end, q4_Low, width=2, color=clr_Low)

// 
//   Information output
// 
// label.new(bar_index, high, text="Q1 start=" + str.tostring(inBar_q1_start) + " end=" + str.tostring(inBar_q1_end) + " High=" + str.tostring(q1_High) + " Low=" + str.tostring(q1_Low))
// label.new(bar_index, high * 0.95, text="Q2 start=" + str.tostring(inBar_q2_start) + " end=" + str.tostring(inBar_q2_end) + " High=" + str.tostring(q2_High) + " Low=" + str.tostring(q2_Low))
// label.new(bar_index, high * 0.9, text="Q3 start=" + str.tostring(inBar_q3_start) + " end=" + str.tostring(inBar_q3_end) + " High=" + str.tostring(q3_High) + " Low=" + str.tostring(q3_Low))
// label.new(bar_index, high * 0.85, text="Q4 start=" + str.tostring(inBar_q4_start) + " end=" + str.tostring(inBar_q4_end) + " High=" + str.tostring(q4_High) + " Low=" + str.tostring(q4_Low))




Try xloc.bar_time
In F_Get_BarIndexAtTime change bar_index for time_close
F_Get_BarIndexAtTime(_time) =>
    var int timeClose = na
    if (_time <= time and (_time > time[1] or bar_index == 0))
        timeClose := time_close
    timeClose

and add xloc in line.new
if not na(inBar_q1_start) and not na(inBar_q1_end) and not na(q1_High) and not na(q1_Low)
    line.new(inBar_q1_start, q1_High, inBar_q1_end, q1_High, width=2, color=clr_High, xloc = xloc.bar_time)
    line.new(inBar_q1_start, q1_Low, inBar_q1_end, q1_Low, width=2, color=clr_Low, xloc = xloc.bar_time)


